# unable to run interpreter in eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, virtualenv

I am unable run interpreter in Eclipse. I made a new interpreter which is loading  *python2.7*  from the Virtual environment. 
When i run the  *manage.py*   file it is giving me error, as it is unable to load the module.

It works fine if I am executing it from terminal, but it gives me error when i run the command from eclipse.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/workspace/tms/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Am i facing this problem because of Ubuntu 11.0, or is there some other problem ?

Can anyone pls help me..

Comment: I would try `import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)` and make sure the path for the virtualenv (including the django lib are included)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your interpreter isn't properly set up. I would suggest configuring a new one. When you select the location of your new interpreter make sure you use the python executable from within your virtualenv (not the system one), that's probably `/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/python`.

When you get to the point where eclipse invites you to add folders to your python path, it's proably easiest just to click 'select all'. This should include all the packages (eg django) from your virtual env.

Then use this new interpreter on your project and eclipse should be able to find the `django.core.management` module (and all the other modules used in your project).

Comment: I have already done everything u suggested.. Still its not working.
When i run it through terminal, it works all fine. but its giving problem when i do it through eclipse.

Comment: probably a stupid question, but you do actually have django installed in your virtualenv? You should be able to see it at /path/to/your/virtualevn/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django

Comment: yes sir .. that was the 1st thing i installed.
As is said earlier, it virtual environment works fine when it is running through terminal. It is giving error when its running  on eclipse..